# Communication between python app and FS Mini-Filter Driver?

Tags: python, pyqt5, kernel

Is there a way for a python app/PyQt5 to connect to Kernel communication port? Basically, I am following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lDhqtjdsq-k&list=PLZ4EgN7ZCzJyUT-FmgHsW4e9BxfP-VMuo&index=14). Unfortunately the example is coded in C++, and I am wondering if there is a library already for connecting to my kernel Mini-Filter driver communication port in python or can I/do I have to use cython?